# Threejs: PointCloudMaterial size compared to ShaderMaterial gl_PointSize with size attenuation

Tags: three.js, webgl, vertex-shader

I am curious to know what the relationship is between `gl_PointSize` and the size property within `PointCloudMaterial`.

When I create a `PointCloud` with `PointCloudMaterial` and set the `size` property to `1`, the size of the particles are far larger than when creating a `PointCloud` with a `ShaderMaterial` and setting the size parameter for the vertex shader to `1`. I also account for size attenuation like in the `PointCloudMaterial` shader:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="particle_vs">
    uniform float size;
    uniform float scale;
    void main() {
        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
        gl_PointSize = size * ( scale / length( mvPosition.xyz ) );
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
    }
</script>
```

I have extracted a simple example of my problem here:
http://dev.cartelle.nl/particle-example/

- The red particles are assigned a `PointCloudMaterial` set to size `1`.
- The green particles are assigned a `ShaderMaterial` that has a `Vertex Shader` that accounts for size attenuation like in `PointCloudMaterial`. I've set the `size` to `300` in this case, and as you can see the green particles are still smaller.

My expected result is to have a `ShaderMaterial` to take the same unit measure as the size property on `PointCloudMaterial`. I have to have both these materials working together, so I'm trying to figure out the relationship between these sizes. Must be something I'm missing with the vertex shader?

Thanks!
Johnny

Comment: FYI - `sortParticles` is no longer a property of `PointCloud`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ShaderMaterial`, you need to set

```
scale: { type: 'f', value: window.innerHeight / 2 },
```

This is because of the following line in the `WebGLRenderer` method `refreshUniformsParticle()`:

```
uniforms.scale.value = _canvas.height / 2.0; // TODO: Cache this.
```

three.js r.71

Comment: I would suggest you confirm this by (1) using the same geometry for both `PointClouds` and (2) removing the `map` in each case.

Comment: Appreciate the quick response - thanks! I've updated the size uniform as suggested. I've also removed the maps and now have shared geometry for both PointClouds like you mentioned. The green particles still display smaller. I must be missing something obvious :) Updates reflected here: http://dev.cartelle.nl/particle-example/

Comment: Although, I just tried setting ShaderMaterial size: { type: 'f', value: window.innerHeight } instead, and this seems to display exactly the size of PointCloudMaterial

Comment: I had a typo in my answer, but `window.innerHeight / 2` works for me.