# TREE.JS / GLSL How to match shader size with world coords?

Tags: three.js, 3d, glsl, shader, scale

It's really weird that I couldn't find the answer to this simple issue.
I am trying to match shader particle size with world coordinates.

```
verts.push(new THREE.Vector3(-2.0, 0.0, 0.0));
colors.push(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
size.push(1.0);

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(verts);
geometry.addAttribute("color", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(colors), 3));
geometry.addAttribute("size", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(size), 1));

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

   uniforms: {

        resolution: new THREE.Uniform(new THREE.Vector2(renderer.domElement.width, renderer.domElement.height)),
        texture: {
        value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(circularPoint) },
        scale: {
        value: window.innerHeight / 2 }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertexShader").textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragmentShader").textContent,
    depthTest : true,
    alphaTest: 0.9

})

material.extensions.fragDepth = true;
material.extensions.drawBuffers = true;

var points = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
scene.add(points);

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 8, 8), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({wireframe: true}));
sphere.position.set(-2.0, 0., 0.0);
scene.add(sphere);
```

I have set particle size to 1.0 and sphere radius to 0.5 hoping that they would be the same, but they don't.

[image]

By experimenting, I have figured out that particle size is linked with camera parameters and canvas dimensions somehow.

Can somebody help me to tweak shader to match everything, so practice size n would be the same size as sphere geometry with radius 0.5 or, i.e cube one with 1.0 sides?

```js
THREE.OrbitControls = function(e, t) {
  var n, o, a, i, r;
  this.object = e, this.domElement = void 0 !== t ? t : document, this.enabled = !0, this.target = new THREE.Vector3, this.minDistance = 0, this.maxDistance = 1 / 0, this.minZoom = 0, this.maxZoom = 1 / 0, this.minPolarAngle = 0, this.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI, this.minAzimuthAngle = -1 / 0, this.maxAzimuthAngle = 1 / 0, this.enableDamping = !1, this.dampingFactor = .25, this.enableZoom = !0, this.zoomSpeed = 1, this.enableRotate = !0, this.rotateSpeed = 1, this.enablePan = !0, this.keyPanSpeed = 7, this.autoRotate = !1, this.autoRotateSpeed = 2, this.enableKeys = !0, this.keys = {
    LEFT: 37,
    UP: 38,
    RIGHT: 39,
    BOTTOM: 40
  }, this.mouseButtons = {
    ORBIT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT,
    ZOOM: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE,
    PAN: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT
  }, this.target0 = this.target.clone(), this.position0 = this.object.position.clone(), this.zoom0 = this.object.zoom, this.getPolarAngle = function() {
    return E.phi
  }, this.getAzimuthalAngle = function() {
    return E.theta
  }, this.saveState = function() {
    s.target0.copy(s.target), s.position0.copy(s.object.position), s.zoom0 = s.object.zoom
  }, this.reset = function() {
    s.target.copy(s.target0), s.object.position.copy(s.position0), s.object.zoom = s.zoom0, s.object.updateProjectionMatrix(), s.dispatchEvent(c), s.update(), u = l.NONE
  }, this.update = (n = new THREE.Vector3, o = (new THREE.Quaternion).setFromUnitVectors(e.up, new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0)), a = o.clone().inverse(), i = new THREE.Vector3, r = new THREE.Quaternion, function() {
    var e = s.object.position;
    return n.copy(e).sub(s.target), n.applyQuaternion(o), E.setFromVector3(n), s.autoRotate && u === l.NONE && M(2 * Math.PI / 60 / 60 * s.autoRotateSpeed), E.theta += p.theta, E.phi += p.phi, E.theta = Math.max(s.minAzimuthAngle, Math.min(s.maxAzimuthAngle, E.theta)), E.phi = Math.max(s.minPolarAngle, Math.min(s.maxPolarAngle, E.phi)), E.makeSafe(), E.radius *= b, E.radius = Math.max(s.minDistance, Math.min(s.maxDistance, E.radius)), s.target.add(g), n.setFromSpherical(E), n.applyQuaternion(a), e.copy(s.target).add(n), s.object.lookAt(s.target), !0 === s.enableDamping ? (p.theta *= 1 - s.dampingFactor, p.phi *= 1 - s.dampingFactor) : p.set(0, 0, 0), b = 1, g.set(0, 0, 0), !(!(T || i.distanceToSquared(s.object.position) > h || 8 * (1 - r.dot(s.object.quaternion)) > h) || (s.dispatchEvent(c), i.copy(s.object.position), r.copy(s.object.quaternion), T = !1))
  }), this.dispose = function() {
    s.domElement.removeEventListener("contextmenu", B, !1), s.domElement.removeEventListener("mousedown", Z, !1), s.domElement.removeEventListener("wheel", F, !1), s.domElement.removeEventListener("touchstart", X, !1), s.domElement.removeEventListener("touchend", _, !1), s.domElement.removeEventListener("touchmove", K, !1), document.removeEventListener("mousemove", Y, !1), document.removeEventListener("mouseup", z, !1), window.removeEventListener("keydown", I, !1)
  };
  var s = this,
    c = {
      type: "change"
    },
    m = {
      type: "start"
    },
    d = {
      type: "end"
    },
    l = {
      NONE: -1,
      ROTATE: 0,
      DOLLY: 1,
      PAN: 2,
      TOUCH_ROTATE: 3,
      TOUCH_DOLLY: 4,
      TOUCH_PAN: 5
    },
    u = l.NONE,
    h = 1e-6,
    E = new THREE.Spherical,
    p = new THREE.Spherical,
    b = 1,
    g = new THREE.Vector3,
    T = !1,
    v = new THREE.Vector2,
    R = new THREE.Vector2,
    O = new THREE.Vector2,
    f = new THREE.Vector2,
    y = new THREE.Vector2,
    H = new THREE.Vector2,
    w = new THREE.Vector2,
    P = new THREE.Vector2,
    j = new THREE.Vector2;

  function C() {
    return Math.pow(.95, s.zoomSpeed)
  }

  function M(e) {
    p.theta -= e
  }

  function L(e) {
    p.phi -= e
  }
  var N, A, k, x = (N = new THREE.Vector3, function(e, t) {
      N.setFromMatrixColumn(t, 0), N.multiplyScalar(-e), g.add(N)
    }),
    D = (A = new THREE.Vector3, function(e, t) {
      A.setFromMatrixColumn(t, 1), A.multiplyScalar(e), g.add(A)
    }),
    U = (k = new THREE.Vector3, function(e, t) {
      var n = s.domElement === document ? s.domElement.body : s.domElement;
      if (s.object.isPerspectiveCamera) {
        var o = s.object.position;
        k.copy(o).sub(s.target);
        var a = k.length();
        a *= Math.tan(s.object.fov / 2 * Math.PI / 180), x(2 * e * a / n.clientHeight, s.object.matrix), D(2 * t * a / n.clientHeight, s.object.matrix)
      } else s.object.isOrthographicCamera ? (x(e * (s.object.right - s.object.left) / s.object.zoom / n.clientWidth, s.object.matrix), D(t * (s.object.top - s.object.bottom) / s.object.zoom / n.clientHeight, s.object.matrix)) : (console.warn("WARNING"), s.enablePan = !1)
    });

  function S(e) {
    s.object.isPerspectiveCamera ? b /= e : s.object.isOrthographicCamera ? (s.object.zoom = Math.max(s.minZoom, Math.min(s.maxZoom, s.object.zoom * e)), s.object.updateProjectionMatrix(), T = !0) : (console.warn("WARNING"), s.enableZoom = !1)
  }

  function V(e) {
    s.object.isPerspectiveCamera ? b *= e : s.object.isOrthographicCamera ? (s.object.zoom = Math.max(s.minZoom, Math.min(s.maxZoom, s.object.zoom / e)), s.object.updateProjectionMatrix(), T = !0) : (console.warn("WARNING"), s.enableZoom = !1)
  }

  function Z(e) {
    if (!1 !== s.enabled) {
      switch (e.preventDefault(), e.button) {
        case s.mouseButtons.ORBIT:
          if (!1 === s.enableRotate) return;
          o = e, v.set(o.clientX, o.clientY), u = l.ROTATE;
          break;
        case s.mouseButtons.ZOOM:
          if (!1 === s.enableZoom) return;
          n = e, w.set(n.clientX, n.clientY), u = l.DOLLY;
          break;
        case s.mouseButtons.PAN:
          if (!1 === s.enablePan) return;
          t = e, f.set(t.clientX, t.clientY), u = l.PAN
      }
      var t, n, o;
      u !== l.NONE && (document.addEventListener("mousemove", Y, !1), document.addEventListener("mouseup", z, !1), s.dispatchEvent(m))
    }
  }

  function Y(e) {
    var t, n;
    if (!1 !== s.enabled) switch (e.preventDefault(), u) {
      case l.ROTATE:
        if (!1 === s.enableRotate) return;
        ! function(e) {
          R.set(e.clientX, e.clientY), O.subVectors(R, v);
          var t = s.domElement === document ? s.domElement.body : s.domElement;
          M(2 * Math.PI * O.x / t.clientWidth * s.rotateSpeed), L(2 * Math.PI * O.y / t.clientHeight * s.rotateSpeed), v.copy(R), s.update()
        }(e);
        break;
      case l.DOLLY:
        if (!1 === s.enableZoom) return;
        n = e, P.set(n.clientX, n.clientY), j.subVectors(P, w), 0 < j.y ? S(C()) : j.y < 0 && V(C()), w.copy(P), s.update();
        break;
      case l.PAN:
        if (!1 === s.enablePan) return;
        t = e, y.set(t.clientX, t.clientY), H.subVectors(y, f), U(H.x, H.y), f.copy(y), s.update()
    }
  }

  function z(e) {
    !1 !== s.enabled && (document.removeEventListener("mousemove", Y, !1), document.removeEventListener("mouseup", z, !1), s.dispatchEvent(d), u = l.NONE)
  }

  function F(e) {
    var t;
    !1 === s.enabled || !1 === s.enableZoom || u !== l.NONE && u !== l.ROTATE || (e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation(), (t = e).deltaY < 0 ? V(C()) : 0 < t.deltaY && S(C()), s.update(), s.dispatchEvent(m), s.dispatchEvent(d))
  }

  function I(e) {
    !1 !== s.enabled && !1 !== s.enableKeys && !1 !== s.enablePan && function(e) {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case s.keys.UP:
          U(0, s.keyPanSpeed), s.update();
          break;
        case s.keys.BOTTOM:
          U(0, -s.keyPanSpeed), s.update();
          break;
        case s.keys.LEFT:
          U(s.keyPanSpeed, 0), s.update();
          break;
        case s.keys.RIGHT:
          U(-s.keyPanSpeed, 0), s.update()
      }
    }(e)
  }

  function X(e) {
    if (!1 !== s.enabled) {
      switch (e.touches.length) {
        case 1:
          if (!1 === s.enableRotate) return;
          r = e, v.set(r.touches[0].pageX, r.touches[0].pageY), u = l.TOUCH_ROTATE;
          break;
        case 2:
          if (!1 === s.enableZoom) return;
          o = (n = e).touches[0].pageX - n.touches[1].pageX, a = n.touches[0].pageY - n.touches[1].pageY, i = Math.sqrt(o * o + a * a), w.set(0, i), u = l.TOUCH_DOLLY;
          break;
        case 3:
          if (!1 === s.enablePan) return;
          t = e, f.set(t.touches[0].pageX, t.touches[0].pageY), u = l.TOUCH_PAN;
          break;
        default:
          u = l.NONE
      }
      var t, n, o, a, i, r;
      u !== l.NONE && s.dispatchEvent(m)
    }
  }

  function K(e) {
    var t, n, o, a, i;
    if (!1 !== s.enabled) switch (e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation(), e.touches.length) {
      case 1:
        if (!1 === s.enableRotate) return;
        if (u !== l.TOUCH_ROTATE) return;
        ! function(e) {
          R.set(e.touches[0].pageX, e.touches[0].pageY), O.subVectors(R, v);
          var t = s.domElement === document ? s.domElement.body : s.domElement;
          M(2 * Math.PI * O.x / t.clientWidth * s.rotateSpeed), L(2 * Math.PI * O.y / t.clientHeight * s.rotateSpeed), v.copy(R), s.update()
        }(e);
        break;
      case 2:
        if (!1 === s.enableZoom) return;
        if (u !== l.TOUCH_DOLLY) return;
        o = (n = e).touches[0].pageX - n.touches[1].pageX, a = n.touches[0].pageY - n.touches[1].pageY, i = Math.sqrt(o * o + a * a), P.set(0, i), j.subVectors(P, w), 0 < j.y ? V(C()) : j.y < 0 && S(C()), w.copy(P), s.update();
        break;
      case 3:
        if (!1 === s.enablePan) return;
        if (u !== l.TOUCH_PAN) return;
        t = e, y.set(t.touches[0].pageX, t.touches[0].pageY), H.subVectors(y, f), U(H.x, H.y), f.copy(y), s.update();
        break;
      default:
        u = l.NONE
    }
  }

  function _(e) {
    !1 !== s.enabled && (s.dispatchEvent(d), u = l.NONE)
  }

  function B(e) {
    !1 !== s.enabled && e.preventDefault()
  }
  s.domElement.addEventListener("contextmenu", B, !1), s.domElement.addEventListener("mousedown", Z, !1), s.domElement.addEventListener("wheel", F, !1), s.domElement.addEventListener("touchstart", X, !1), s.domElement.addEventListener("touchend", _, !1), s.domElement.addEventListener("touchmove", K, !1), window.addEventListener("keydown", I, !1), this.update()
}, THREE.OrbitControls.prototype = Object.create(THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype), THREE.OrbitControls.prototype.constructor = THREE.OrbitControls, Object.defineProperties(THREE.OrbitControls.prototype, {
  center: {
    get: function() {
      return console.warn("THREE.OrbitControls"), this.target
    }
  },
  noZoom: {
    get: function() {
      return console.warn("THREE.OrbitControls"), !this.enableZoom
    },
    set: function(e) {
      console.warn("THREE.OrbitControls"), this.enableZoom = !e
    }
  },
  noRotate: {
    get: function() {
      return console.warn("THREE.OrbitControls"), !this.enableRotate
    },
    set: function(e) {
      console.warn("THREE.OrbitControls"), this.enableRotate = !e
    }
  },
  noPan: {
    get: function() {
      return console.warn("THREE.OrbitControls"), !this.enablePan
    },
    set: function(e) {
      console.warn("THREE.OrbitControls"), this.enablePan = !e
    }
  },
  noKeys: {
    get: function() {
      return console.warn("THREE.OrbitControls"), !this.enableKeys
    },
    set: function(e) {
      console.warn("THREE.OrbitControls"), this.enableKeys = !e
    }
  },
  staticMoving: {
    get: function() {
      return console.warn("THREE.OrbitControls"), !this.enableDamping
    },
    set: function(e) {
      console.warn("THREE.OrbitControls"), this.enableDamping = !e
    }
  },
  dynamicDampingFactor: {
    get: function() {
      return console.warn("THREE.OrbitControls"), this.dampingFactor
    },
    set: function(e) {
      console.warn("THREE.OrbitControls"), this.dampingFactor = e
    }
  }
});

var circularPoint = "data:image/png;base64,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";

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE, 1.0);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var verts = [],
  colors = [],
  size = [];

verts.push(new THREE.Vector3(-2.0, 0.0, 0.0));

colors.push(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

size.push(1.0);

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(verts);
geometry.addAttribute("color", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(colors), 3));
geometry.addAttribute("size", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(size), 1));

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({

  uniforms: {

    resolution: new THREE.Uniform(new THREE.Vector2(renderer.domElement.width, renderer.domElement.height)),
    texture: {
      value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(circularPoint)
    },
    scale: {
      value: window.innerHeight / 2
    }
  },
  vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertexShader").textContent,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragmentShader").textContent,
  depthTest: true,
  alphaTest: 0.9


})

material.extensions.derivatives = true;
material.extensions.fragDepth = true;
material.extensions.drawBuffers = true;

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 8, 8), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
  wireframe: true
}));
sphere.position.set(-2.0, 0., 0.0);
scene.add(sphere);

var points = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
scene.add(points);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var inverseMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
var ray = new THREE.Ray();

renderer.domElement.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);

function onMouseMove(event) {

  camera.clearViewOffset();

  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>THREE.JS | D3.JS : 3D SCATTERPLOT [rc]</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Ehno based on D3.JS | THREE.JS stack.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,CSV,JavaScript,D3.JS,THREE.JS">
  <meta name="author" content="Vladimir V. KUCHINOV">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/98/three.min.js"></script>


</head>

<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">

  attribute float size; attribute vec3 color; uniform float scale; uniform vec2 resolution; varying vec3 vColor; void main() { vColor = color; vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 ); gl_PointSize = size * ( scale / -mvPosition.z ); gl_Position
  = projectionMatrix * mvPosition; }


</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">

  varying vec3 vColor; uniform sampler2D texture; void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.); gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor * texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord); if (gl_FragColor.a
  < 0.1) discard; } </script>

    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: too lazy to analyze the code but check if both sphere and particle go through the same math ... (same matrices) my bet is one of them is not going through perspective transform/division ... or the depth coordinate is not the same

Comment: Shader has depthTest and fragDepth to true and while particle and sphere have the same coords, don't think it's a depth coords issue. What do you mean by perspective transform/division?

Comment: the usage of `projectionMatrix`  must be the same way for both entities. once you use perspective projection matrix the transformed Vertexes will be divided by the `w` coordinate of the result (by OpenGL implementation,  that is called the perspective division and if the w is not the same like differnet matrces or math the resulting coordiantes will be different)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to be aware of is that the `gl_PointSize` value in a `THREE.Points` shader always translates to *pixels*, not world coordinates. So a `gl_PointSize = 2.0;` statement will be 2 pixels wide & tall, regardless of how tall your browser window is. You have to manually convert from px to world coordinates by passing a `uniform float` of the viewport height, since the perspective camera's height determines the scaling of the world:

```
uniforms: {
    viewport: { value: window.innerHeight },
}
```

Then you can use this value to multiply by your diameter in the shader

```
gl_PointSize = viewport * radius / -mvPosition.z;
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that by setting your pixel ratio to a higher DPI with `renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);`, you're also adding more pixels, so you have to take that into consideration when declaring your uniform:

```
uniforms: {
    viewport: {value: window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio },
}
```

I re-created a simplified version of your example with two points, one inside a plane with width and height of 1 world units, and a sphere with radius of 0.5. (I removed all OrbitControls stuff to keep it simple). Notice I also added a `'resize'` event listener at the bottom to re-calculate all relevant values when the window is resized.

```js
var circularPoint = "data:image/png;base64,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";
var circleTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(circularPoint);

// Three.js boilerplate
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE, 1.0);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);

// Build Plane
var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1, 4, 4);
var normMat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({
 wireframe: true
});
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeom, normMat);
plane.position.set(-2.0, 0., 0.0);
scene.add(plane);

// Build Sphere
var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0.5, 16, 16);
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeom, normMat);
sphere.position.set(2.0, 0., 0.0);
scene.add(sphere);

// Build points
var verts = [],
 colors = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5],
 radius = [0.5, 0.5];

// Green point at x: -2
verts.push(new THREE.Vector3(-2.0, 0.0, 0.0));

// Pink point at x: +2
verts.push(new THREE.Vector3(2.0, 0.0, 0.0));

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(verts);
geometry.addAttribute("color", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(colors), 3));
geometry.addAttribute("radius", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(radius), 1));

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
 uniforms: {
  viewport: {value: window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio },
  texture: {value: circleTexture}
 },
 vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertexShader").textContent,
 fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragmentShader").textContent,
  transparent: true
});

var points = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
scene.add(points);

// We move the camera to generate animation & sense of depth
renderer.setAnimationLoop((t) => {
 camera.position.set(
      Math.sin(t * 0.0007) * 7,
      Math.sin(t * 0.0005) * 3,
      Math.cos(t * 0.0003) * 7
  );
 camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
 renderer.render(scene, camera)
});

// We must recalculate all values when window is resized
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  material.uniforms.viewport.value = window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
  console.log("viewport uniform: " + material.uniforms.viewport.value);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>THREE.JS | D3.JS : 3D SCATTERPLOT [rc]</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Ehno based on D3.JS | THREE.JS stack.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,CSV,JavaScript,D3.JS,THREE.JS">
  <meta name="author" content="Vladimir V. KUCHINOV">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/98/three.min.js"></script>


</head>

<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShader">
#define PI 3.141592
attribute float radius;
attribute vec3 color;

uniform float viewport;
varying vec3 vColor;
void main() {
  vColor = color;
  
  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
  gl_PointSize = viewport * radius * PI / -mvPosition.z;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}


</script>

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShader">

  varying vec3 vColor;
  uniform sampler2D texture;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 0.5) * texture2D(texture, gl_PointCoord);;
  }
  </script>

    <body>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Cheers!

Comment: Good answer! I remembered about something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30548534/4045502). And internally, renderer still does that [thing](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L2185L2186) with a half of height, and then in the shader it does [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/points_vert.glsl.js#L19L27).

Comment: It's a good answer, but not perfect. http://vault.vkuchinov.co.uk/test/screen.png. Live demo http://vault.vkuchinov.co.uk/test/

Comment: But maybe it would be enough for my project. Have to figure out how to project two end/start particles onto this median second shader. To be able to draw anything between them via the second shader fragment part. That's my final intention.

Comment: PS: Have a feeling that this concept could be done simply by taking canvas 'screenshot' and doing a partial 2D drawing, while it has to be done with disabled orbit controls, so there would be no 3d transformations.

Comment: @VVK That screenshot demonstrates an apparent bulging of the sphere due to its proximity to the camera. [I wrote a post about that effect](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/constant-distance-between-sprite-and-sphere/4473/2?u=marquizzo) explaining how that's the normal behavior of perspective. I also added 2 possible fixes in that post, hopefully they can help you find a solution.

Comment: Cheers, I will look later, by now I am experimenting to projects magenta and cyan particles positions (world coords) to second shader (yellow) to be able to draw anything between them, i.e. line or whatever. http://vault.vkuchinov.co.uk/test2/

Comment: Arghhh, have managed to get projections for two particles into another shader, but couldn't figure setting to draw a line between them. http://vault.vkuchinov.co.uk/test2